# How can I install VEP (Ensembl Variant Effect Predictor)?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I am trying to install VEP through [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ckandoth/61c65ba96b011f286220fa4832ad2bc0). I do not have conda, so first I am trying to install it into `$HOME/miniconda3` as  mentioned:

```
curl -sL https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh
sh /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp $HOME/miniconda3
```

After I run the above commands I am getting this error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /tmp/miniconda.sh
```

If you could help me solve my problem, I would be more than thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer to your question:**

Try doing `chmod +x /tmp/miniconda.sh` then re run `sh /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp $HOME/miniconda3`

This command makes the `.sh` executable. Then rerun your command.

**Another way to download and install miniconda (same as conda only for command-line):**

If you want to get miniconda, I suggest downloading the latest `.sh` file from [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers).

then run `chmod +x downloadedfilename.sh`

and finally execute it: `./downloadedfilename.sh`.

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked !

Comment: My pleasure! please select the answer as accepted or give upvotes so others can be sure about it @eleni.ps